# ambiguous overload for 'operator =' in 'authlog = myfile'

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a game that can save your progress.
I already did this and it worked but now it doesn't work anymore.

**Error:**

> 43: Ambiguous overload for 'operator=' in 'authlog = myfile'
>       note: candidates are: std::basic_string<_CharT,_Traits,_Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT,*Traits,*..........etc

The code that is causing the error:

```
if ( myfile.is_open() )
    {
         while ( getline ( myfile,line ) )
         {
             cout << "You already have a save file!\n";   
         }
         myfile.close();
         myfile.clear();
         authlog = myfile;
         myfile.open("username.txt");
         cout << "Enter your username:\n";
         cin >> auth;
         if( auth == authlog )
         {

         }
    }
```

Comment: What is the type of `authlog`?

Comment: this is not the code causing error...please submit authlog code..

Comment: Authlog is a string but not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, that error can be solved by casting one operand as the other - in other words, it looks like authlog may not be the same type as myfile.

edit: In this case, you are also clearing the file, so maybe you would rather do authlog = "";

In any case, you cannot treat a file as a string.  You can save strings to it or get strings out of it, but it is not a string.

Comment: Thanks but im trying to identify if string auth is equal to string authlog. Even if i do 'if( auth == myfile ) it still won't work.

Comment: Right - that is because myfile is not a string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to every one that answered.
The problem is that i forgot to put

```
while ( getline ( myfile,auth ) )
```

in the code.